# Assigning worker tasks

Tags: javascript, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

In a simulation, workers must move around a map performing tasks.

Each simulation 'tick', they can move one square.

Performing the task once they are adjacent to it takes 10 ticks.

Task squares cannot be passed through.  Squares with workers on cannot be passed through.  More than one worker can work on a square.

Workers are not competing with each other; the objective is to complete all the tasks as quickly as possible.

**Added:** ideally the algorithm should be straightforward to conceptualise and simple to implement.  Isn't that what everybody wants?  Its a big plus if its efficient e.g. the model can be updated and reused, rather than recalculated from scratch often.  Ideally it'll be able to use local optima so its not trying to brute-force an NP problem, but avoid being overtly greedy and think ahead a bit, rather than essentially random wanderings where workers pay little heed of the plans of others.

Here is an example:

[image]

Workers 1 and 2 must complete the tasks on squares A,B,C and D.

How do you decide which worker does which task?

It seems self-evident that 1 should do A and 2 should do C.

1 is 4 squares away from A, so will have finished doing it in 14 ticks. Where should 1 go next, and why?

And what if there was another task - E - is placed directly above B?

What is the logic that a worker uses to decide where to proceed next?

What I've tried:

This being a hobby RTS game, I've tried making it so idle workers proceed to the nearest task, or proceed to the nearest task which no other workers are doing.

This greedy approach has proved to be glaringly inefficient and player testing makes it clear its untenable.  Because the strategic mining/building/farming is key to the game, and because I don't want the player to micro-manage and route all workers, I'm looking for a fairly fair and reasonably optimal algorithm that workers can use instead.

Comment: Sounds like a variation of [the TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: It's more related to multi agent and distributed ai than just TSP. It has many parameters like how much each worker can see, do you have a central node or not and so many other things. you should determine environment specifications and then propose a solution.

Comment: Am I right that new tasks can appear at any time irrespective of other tasks, and you want task assignments to quickly update when this happens?

Comment: @JordanGray absolutely.  Also tasks can be removed from the task-list by the user too.

Comment: I have a question. Since there is no direct solution for your problem (it being TS) Could you perhaps elaborate on your best and worst case scenarios for different workers? For example what's the maximum amount of nodes that a worker will have to hit? How many concurrent workers are we looking at?

Comment: Cross posted after not receiving the answers they wanted: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61726/assigning-tasks-closed

Comment: Try all possibilities!

Answer (score 11):

Even with one worker this is an NP-complete optimization problem (it then becomes the traveling salesman problem) so let's forget about "optimal".

If you know that worker 1 will handle tasks A1, A2, ..., worker 2 will handle tasks B1, B2, ... and so on, then you can, after that decision is made, try to solve the independent traveling salesman problems one by one, and you get the schedules and paths for all your workers.

However, the problem is that you can't know how long it takes to complete a set of tasks A1, A2, ... for a worker before you have solved the traveling salesman problem for that set because walking time impacts the total time to carry out the tasks.

Because it's just a game, and the workers can be assumed to be not optimal thinkers, I would use a stochastic process:

1. Assign all tasks to all workers randomly
2. Use a greedy algorithm to calculate an upper bound on the walking time for every worker within the worker's task group
3. Try a random move, either move one task from one worker to another, or swap tasks between two workers
4. Accept that move based on tabu search or simulated annealing principles, depending on whether the move decreases the upper bound on maximum execution time (walking time + task execution time), so that the goal is to get the last task to finish as early as possible
5. After N iterations, stop, and calculate better solutions to the traveling salesman subproblems e.g. using stochastic search, or explicitly if the problems are small (e.g. less than 10 tasks per worker)

Comment: +1 I was about to suggest the same.

Comment: I like this answer from a scientific point of view. With the additional knowledge that we are talking about a game, I'm a bit unsure whether this idea will bring fun to players because of several reasons. "Unsure" means I'm in doubt a bit and maybe I'm right, maybe not. I still like the approach to the problem in general.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of greedily assigning workers to the nearest task, try greedily assigning the most distant task to its "nearest" worker - that is, the worker whose path passes closely and has enough slack time to handle it. This way you have a (greedy) notion of  the smallest time it takes to complete all the tasks.

For example:

D is the 'most distant task', even without defining that term yet, so assign D to 1. It is 15+10 units away, so set `t` = 25 and the slack on 2 to 25.

Now here is the distance cost of assigning the next task, taking into account shortest routes.

```
    A   B   C   D  
1  10  22  24   -
2  29  19  18   -
```

But here is the true cost according to the greedy idea; the increase to the maximum time `t`.

```
    A   B   C   D  
1  10  22  24   -
2   4  0    0   -
```

Since C has the highest cost (it's the most dangerous task from a greedy perspective), 
assign C to 2.

The next costs are as follows

```
    A   B   slack    A  B
1  10  22     0     10 22
2  21  11  (-)7     14  4
```

Assign B because 22 is the largest increase to the max time `t`. Assign it to worker 2.

...

There are many approaches to a knapsack problem but if simplicity is desired this is probably the next thing to try. Maybe store the shortest paths between tasks. It's an overtly greedy way that does think ahead a bit!

Answer (score 5):

This indeed sounds a lot like the (already mentioned) Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) for multiple agents. Which is actually a problem similar to Multiple knapsack (MKP, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multiple_knapsack_problem) or even Bin packing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

There is a group of algorithms which might be suitable in this situation, and it is called 'Ant colony optimization' (ACO, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms).

To combine the two, there are implementations that use ACO to solve MKP problems; this seems like a good way to go in this case, for example:

http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221246039_Probabilistic_Model_of_Ant_Colony_Optimization_for_Multiple_Knapsack_Problem

Answer (score 3):

Because it is an RTS game I would try to choose a simple, fast, and easy-to-understand approach.

1. It has to be **fast** because performance matters
2. It must be **easy to understand** why a worker goes here and there because in a game you want minions to behave as expected. Don't try to think for the players.

First, of course, I would try the greedy approach. But you already mentioned that it just doesn't work.

Next I would try something like a second-order greedy algorithm. Each worker chooses the closest task A and then chooses the closest tasks B next to A. They try (!) to choose tasks nobody have chosen so far. Something like that.

Keep it small and simple. And mind you: No matter what algorithm you chose, there **will** be a case where it fails miserably. After all there is [no free lunch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something similar to [TobiMcNamobi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713984/758345)’s approach, but more refined:

- Initialize an empty workqueue for each worker and a time `z` it will take to finish this queue.
- Give each task a property `d`, set to 0. It signifies how much this task “is already handled” according to the current plan.
- Repeat till all workers have at least one job **and** (`z` > some fixed value **or** a given amount of time has passed):

  - Take one of the workers `w` with minimal `z`.

    - Set `p` to the position of the latest entry in `w`’s queue or `w`’s position if the
      queue is empty.
    - Loop over the tasks not in this workers queue in order of distance to `p`

      - Calculate `distance/d`
      - If you find a minimum for this value, add this task to the worker’s queue, add the distance to the task + 7 to `z` and add `1/z` to `d`. Break the loop.

Before you run this, you should sort the workers according to distance to the closest task. Otherwise the first task is given rather random and the first task is the most important one.

You can update this whenever a job or a worker is added. Reusing some of the previous values (maybe store intermediate results, like adding the matching `z` to tasks in worker’s queue), this update should be rather fast.

This also probably needs to be updated once in a while anyways, because this algorithm gets quite inaccurate once you go far enough into the future.

The `distance/d` formula might also need some tweaking, but I guess tests would help a lot here.

The definition of “minimum” is up to you. I would recommend taking a local minumum, maybe checking 5 more tasks at maximum. Finding the global minimum seems unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: The way you've presented your answer is a model to other answers! :D

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing "real time" greediness turns out to be bad because workers end up on wild goose chases toward tasks that will be complete or nearly so by the time they arrive. So I'll propose a planning algorithm: a way of intelligently assigning each worker to a sequence of tasks where the union of sequences is a cover.

As others have said the TSP is embedded in this planning requirement, so this is an NP Hard problem.

But there is an easy polynomial time approximation algorithm for the TSP that produces a path no more than 2x optimal in length.  Just compute a minimum spanning tree including all the work sites plus one of the workers.  Then the obvious path traversing each edge once in each direction touches every node.

Of course, when backtracking you can "bee-line" past already-visited nodes.  This means  just emit the task sequence by traversing the MST in pre-order.  Due to the triangle inequality, this path is often quite a bit better than 2x optimal.  (I'm assuming diagonal steps are allowed here.  Otherwise this isn't true, but the algorithm still works fine.)

So an approach to planning is this:

1. Compute a MST for each worker and all work sites.
2. Use the MST associated with each worker W to compute a pre-order path: S_W, T_Wi, i = 1, 2....  Here, S_W is the starting location of worker W. and the T_Wi are task locations in the order W will visit them.
3. Now do a simple event-driven simulation to build a plan as below. (This is an "inner" simulation within the game simulation, just to build a plan.)

In the algorithm below, events include a projected clock time of occurrence and are placed on the event queue with this time as the key.

```
Let Arrive(W, T, L) be an arrival event of worker W 
  at task T starting from previous location L, traveling the shortest path
Let Complete(W, T) be a completion event for worker W of task T

For each worker W, place Arrive(W, T_W1, S_W) on the queue
While events are left on the queue
  Remove an event E
  If E is an arrival Arrive(W, TW_i, L) 
    If TW_i has no worker yet, 
      Assign TW_i to W
      Schedule a future event Complete(W, TW_i) 10 time units in the future.
    Else // T has a worker
      Schedule Arrive(W, TW_{i+1}, L), if TW_{i+1} exists
  Else E is a completion Complete(W, TW_i)
    Schedule Arrive(W, TW_{i+1}, TW_i), if TW_{i+1} exists
```

Now execute the assignments for each worker in the order they were discovered in this (inner) simulation.

The arrival times are computed using the previous location and destination to obtain a most direct route.

This algorithm is fairly greedy, but it's greedy "in advance."  Because you're simulating to assign tasks in advance, you will never send a worker on a wild goose chase to a task that will be finished or well begun by another worker before it arrives.

Additionally, no worker will ever cover more distance than 2x an optimal TSP route.

Comment: A very clear explanation; I have worked it through in my head for a few scenarios and it seems to work.  This is the approach I will implement.

Comment: @Will Cool. Please come back to say how it turned out!

Answer (score 2):

(Note: After doing all this I realize you said 14 ticks because by "adjacent" you were thinking "on top of" while I interpreted it as "next to"... so keep in mind my calculations are based on that, but it shouldn't change the result by much.)

My first instinct would be to first build an independent queue for each worker based on optimal time to complete, assuming no other workers exist and deal with the conflicts later (note that according to my interpretation, when 1 is done with A, then B is closer than D, but a key thing we want to prevent is 1 taking B):

```
1 [A, B, C, D]
2 [C, B, A, D]
```

Then I would calculate a Move+Work Time for each one:

```
1 [A=3+10, B=8+10, C=1+10, D=20+10]
2 [C=7+10, B=1+10, A=10+10, D=11+10]
```

For reference, here's just the total ticks:

```
1 [A=13, B=18, C=11, D=30]
2 [C=17, B=11, A=20, D=21]
```

And here it is cumulatively:

```
1 [A=13, B=31, C=42, D=72]
2 [C=17, B=28, A=48, D=69]
```

So what happens if you just iterate through every task to see who has the lowest time and remove it from the other workers' queues? Obviously as soon as you change something, the cumulative times all will have to be recalculated (which I'm about to do manually, ugh)

Start (same as above):

```
1 [A=13, B=31, C=42, D=72]
2 [C=17, B=28, A=48, D=69]
```

1 has the lowest A time, so 2 loses it, and 2's D time is recalculated:

```
1 [A=13, B=31, C=42, D=72]
2 [C=17, B=28, D=59]
```

2 wins B, so 1's times change again for C and D:

```
1 [A=13, C=32, D=62]
2 [C=17, B=28, D=59]
```

2 wins C, again changing 1's D time:

```
1 [A=13, D=24]
2 [C=17, B=28, D=59]
```

1 wins D:

```
1 [A=13, D=24]
2 [C=17, B=28]
```

What if there was another task E directly above B?  I'm sorry I didn't have time to calculate this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the appearance of the workers need to resemble what a human would do (the algorithm need to assign each work as a human might). If the algorithm does not, a player will wonder what the AI is 
doing and probably try to route manually (even if it is less optimal). I think any "globaly optimal" solution would probably not resemble what a human would do...

So, I would argue that your (Will) initial algorithm might just need a slight improvment to work. Let each worker head to the nearest vaccant job, but simulate it going there and stop the simulation when the worker reach the job or another worker is free that is closer (then that worker will grab that job). If no vaccant jobs may be reached, choose the closest occupied job and help there.